# How to auto confirm question with parted tool using Ansible in Linux

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat

I'm trying to run `/usr/sbin/parted /dev/vdc resizepart 1 4.0GB` using Ansible playbooks, but this command asks the question "Warning: Shrinking can cause problems...." to which I want to answer `y` automatically. The resize will be done to a newly created volume that has a partition **(/dev/vdc1)**, meaning that the is no data that will be lost. I can run the mentioned above in the shell and it works perfectly, whether is extending the space or shrinking it.

**Things I've tried**

1. Ansible module `expect` but it timeout because it expecting the question which I've tried to write it in multiple ways and it doesn't reads the question.
2. Ansible module `parted` but it gets stuck in the same question. This happens because when Ansible sees any word like **Warning** or **Error** it fails immediately. For this case I tried to ignore warnings by using the `ignore_unreachable: false` but it seems this is only useful when connecting to a host.
3. Ansible module `shell` to execute the command `(echo y; echo;) | /usr/sbin/parted /dev/vdc resizepart 1 4.0GB` but it didn't worked. I also tried `(resizepart 1 4.0GB; echo y; echo;) | /usr/sbin/parted /dev/vdc` and again it gets stuck with the question.
4. `fdisk` does not have resize and it requires to delete a partition and recreate it, neither does `sgdisk` have resize.
5. I tried `/usr/sbin/parted -s /dev/vdc resizepart 1 4.0GB` with the `-s` option so that it disables script prompts but it just ignores the answer and it exits the command.

**Questions**

1. Is there's anyway to ignore the warnings in Ansible in order to answer it?
2. How can I shrink a partition using Ansible without having to recreate it? Why do extra work when resizepart exists?
3. Could I auto accept the question is parted?

Comment: Why are you using `ignore_unreachable`? Did you mean to use `ignore_errors`? I would also consider using `changed_when` and `failed_when`.

Comment: Regarding [`parted` module – Configure block device partitions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/parted_module.html), can you provide the task, debug output, error messages, etc.? For "_Could I auto accept the question is parted?_" see [GNU `parted` `resizepart` in script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365657/266568)

Comment: @Squashman Yeah, I was using the wrong one, thanks.
@U880D The error was from Ansible saying that a warning appeared in the shell command which was `Warning: Shrinking this partition can get to data loss. Continue? (Yes/No)?`

Comment: I ended up using `fdisk`, which works for both Ansible and shell and it doesn't requires to accept anything. I didn't wanted to use `fdisk` because I had to delete the partition first which was damaging the boot sequence. It turns out that since I'm using RHEL 8, it doesn't allow me to resize the root partition below 20GB. I used the following commands to resize:
`(echo d; echo 3; echo n; echo 3; echo ; echo +23GB; echo w) | fdisk /dev/vda`
and then the following to create a new partition using the rest of space:
`(echo n; echo 4; echo ; echo ; echo w) | fdisk /dev/vda`